# How to use Phone Data service if WiFi is not available?

Tags: android, httpclient, 3g, android-wifi, android-wireless

I am making an app and I want it to be allowed to use 3G or any data network when WiFi is not available. How would I implement this? I am using HTTPClients to make calls everytime an SMS is received. It works, but it would be perfect if it could run when WiFi is not available, of course this option would be user defined (Check if you wish to use data network if WiFi is unavailable) so the user has full control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I figured out that it automatically uses 3G resources if you have the correct permission to use 3G or any data network available.